# Maurer-Cartan form and left-invariant vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-forms

A left-invariant vector field on a Lie group $G$ satisfies

$$
(L_g)_*X = X
$$

for all $g\in G$. So we have in particular $\omega(X_p)=(L_{g^{-1}})X_p=X_e$ with $\omega$ the Maurer-Cartan form on $G$.

Please have a look at [this derivation of the Maurer-Cartan equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurer%E2%80%93Cartan_form#Properties). It says that if $X$ and $Y$ are left-invariant vector fields, then they satisfy

$$\tag{1}X(\omega(Y))=Y(\omega(X))=0$$

Why is that true? I only get

$$
X(\omega(Y))=X(Y)=[X,Y]
$$

so

$$
X(\omega(Y))-Y(\omega(X))=X(Y)-Y(X)=[X,Y]-[Y,X]=2[X,Y]
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should start from the *Cartan Formula* which is
$$d\omega(X,Y)=X(\omega(Y))-Y(\omega(X))-\omega([X,Y])$$
Then since $X(\omega(Y))$ and $Y(\omega(X))$ are $0$ then you have
$$d\omega(X,Y)+\omega([X,Y])=0.$$

In fact $\omega(Y)$ is a constant since $Y$ is left-invariant. If $\omega(Y)$ is a constant then whatever derivativeyou will apply you will obtain $0$. Being more precise if you have a vector field $X$ which at the end of the story is some kind of derivative and therefore you have $$X(\omega(Y))=0$$.

Comment: Hmm, what you are saying makes sense to me, but what's wrong with the last two equations in my question? If $\omega(X)=X$, then $X(\omega(Y))$ reduces to $X(Y)$ which is per definition equal to $[X,Y]$.

Comment: I can't se why $X(\omega(Y))$  should be equal to $[X,Y]$. In general $[X,Y](f)=X(Y(f))-Y(X(f)).$ As far as I can see $X(\omega(Y))=X(Y)$ is not implied by the left invariance of $X$ and $Y$

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurer%E2%80%93Cartan_form#Construction_of_the_Maurer.E2.80.93Cartan_form): *A left-invariant vector field is a section X of TG such that $(L_g)_*X=X$.* This means that $\omega(X)=X$, so $Y(\omega(X))=Y(X)$. And $Y(X)$ is defined as $[Y,X]$.

Comment: Why $Y(X)$ should be defined as $[Y,X]$? If $X,Y$ are vector fields (left-invariant or not) you have by the very definition of the commutator that $[Y,X](f)=Y(X(f))-X(Y(f))$.

Comment: In the place you cited he's referring to a specific 1-form $\omega_g$ and not to a generic 1-form $\omega$

Comment: Maurer Cartan form Is not really explained everywhere. I can suggest you Spivak (2nd book), Fecko (Differential Geoemtry of Lie Groups) and if you have time and patience I would suggest you to read some chapters here and there of "Boothby, An Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds and Riemannian Geometry". He's really pedantic but at the end I found it really clarifying. This parte is explained in chapter 4-7 and maybe 8 (something here and something there). If you find other simple and interesting books on the subject please tell me....

Comment: To be precise you need that $Y$ is left invariant so that $\omega (Y)$ is constant

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to write a answer with distinguished notations, as in  [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurer%E2%80%93Cartan_form#Properties) there's a little abuse of notation without distinguishing elements in the Lie algebra and left invariant vector fields, which feels like the main source of confusion.

Let's write $X \in \mathfrak{g}$, $\mathfrak{g} = T_eG$ the Lie algebra of $G$, and its corresponding left invariant vector field $\tilde{X} \in \mathfrak{X}(G)^L$ with $L_{g,*}\tilde{X}_{h} = \tilde{X}_{gh}$ for all $g, h \in G$. Also $\omega_g(\tilde{X}_g) = L_{g^{-1},*}\tilde{X}_g=\tilde{X}_e=X$. Then the formulation in wiki should be clearer now:

Let $X, Y \in \mathfrak{g}$ and $\tilde{X}, \tilde{Y} \in \mathfrak{X}(G)^L$. Since $\omega_g(\tilde{X}_g)=X \in \mathfrak{g}$ is a constant function of $g \in G$ in the same fibre $T_eG$, its Lie derivative w.r.t. any vector field $Z \in \mathfrak{X}(G)$ vanishes
$$
Z(\omega(\tilde{X}))_g=\mathcal{L}_Z\omega(\tilde{X})_g =\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right\vert_{t=0}\phi_g(t)^*\omega(\tilde{X}) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right\vert_{t=0} X = 0,
$$
where $\phi_g(t)$ is a flow of $Z$ defined in a neighborhood of $g \in G$, and the calculation becomes

\begin{align}
d\omega(\tilde{X}, \tilde{Y}) & =\tilde{X}(\omega(\tilde{Y}))-\tilde{Y}(\omega(\tilde{X}))-\omega([\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}]) \\
& =\tilde{X}(Y)-\tilde{Y}(X)-\omega([\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}]) \\
&= -\omega([\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}]).
\end{align}

By the way, when we write $XY$ we usually mean applying $Y$ first then $X$. Acting on a smooth function $f \in C^\infty(M)$, $XYf = X(Yf)$. More precisely, in a local coordinate $(U,x^1,\cdots,x^n)$, write $X = \sum X^i\partial_i$ and $Y = \sum Y^j\partial_j$, we have $XYf = \sum X^i \partial_i(Y^j\partial_jf) = \sum X^i (\partial_iY^j)\partial_jf + \sum X^i 
 Y^j \partial_i\partial_jf$.